# FILE_APPEND not working properly with file_put_contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, local-storage

I'm passing form data as JSON via AJAX to a PHP file which then saves the JSON in a text file on the server.

The problem is that when I use FILE_APPEND the data is not written on the file when the JSON data already exists in the text file.

My HTML code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="eloqua.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        localStorage.clear();

        $("form").on("submit", function() {
            if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
                var fields = $(this).serialize();

                localStorage.setItem("eloqua-fields", JSON.stringify( fields ));
                alert("Stored Succesfully");
                $(this).find("input[type=text]").val("");
                alert("Now Passing stored data to Server through AJAX jQuery");
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "backend.php",         
                   data: fields
                });
            } else {
                alert("Storage Failed. Try refreshing");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {

    var a=document.forms["EloquaForm"]["C_FirstName"].value;
    if (a==null || a=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }

    var b=document.forms["EloquaForm"]["C_LastName"].value;
    if (b==null || b=="")
      {
      alert("Last name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }

    var y=document.forms["EloquaForm"]["C_EmailAddress"].value;
    var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length)
      {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p><img src="red-asterix.jpeg"> indicates a required field</p>

    <div class="form-container" style="width: 625px">
    <form class="form-eloqua" name="EloquaForm" action="http://s33.t.eloqua.com/e/f2" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    <span class="form-eloqua-label"><span>First Name</span></span><input id="firstname" type="text" name="C_FirstName" />
    <span class="form-eloqua-label"><span>Last Name</span></span><input id="lastname" type="text" name="C_LastName" />
    <span class="form-eloqua-label"><span>Email Address</span></span><input id="email" type="text" name="C_EmailAddress" />
    <span class="form-eloqua-label">Title</span><input id="title" type="text" name="C_Title" />
    <span class="form-eloqua-label">Company</span><input id="company" type="text" name="C_Company" />
    <span class="form-eloqua-label">ZIP or Postal Code</span><input id="postcode" type="text" name="zipOrPostalCode" />
    <span class="form-eloqua-label">Country</span><select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="">Please select ...</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AG">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AA">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="BL">Bonaire</option>
    <option value="BA">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="BC">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
    <option value="BN">Brunei</option>
    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="IC">Canary Islands</option>
    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
    <option value="CD">Channel Islands</option>
    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>
    <option value="CI">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="CS">Cocos Island</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
    <option value="CC">Comoros</option>
    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="CT">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
    <option value="CB">Curacao</option>
    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="TM">East Timor</option>
    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="FA">Falkland Islands</option>
    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="FS">French Southern Ter</option>
    <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="GB">Great Britain</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
    <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
    <option value="HW">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="IA">Iran</option>
    <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
    <option value="IR">Ireland</option>
    <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="NK">Korea North</option>
    <option value="KS">Korea South</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="LA">Laos</option>
    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
    <option value="LY">Libya</option>
    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="MO">Macau</option>
    <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="ME">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="MI">Midway Islands</option>
    <option value="MD">Moldova</option>
    <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="NA">Nambia</option>
    <option value="NU">Nauru</option>
    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
    <option value="AN">Netherland Antilles</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevis</option>
    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="NW">Niue</option>
    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="PW">Palau Island</option>
    <option value="PS">Palestine</option>
    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
    <option value="PO">Pitcairn Island</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="ME">Republic of Montenegro</option>
    <option value="RS">Republic of Serbia</option>
    <option value="RE">Reunion</option>
    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
    <option value="RU">Russia</option>
    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="NT">St Barthelemy</option>
    <option value="EU">St Eustatius</option>
    <option value="HE">St Helena</option>
    <option value="KN">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
    <option value="LC">St Lucia</option>
    <option value="MB">St Maarten</option>
    <option value="PM">St Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
    <option value="VC">St Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
    <option value="SP">Saipan</option>
    <option value="SO">Samoa</option>
    <option value="AS">Samoa American</option>
    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
    <option value="ST">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="OI">Somalia</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="SY">Syria</option>
    <option value="TA">Tahiti</option>
    <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="TZ">Tanzania</option>
    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
    <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
    <option value="TT">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
    <option value="TU">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="TC">Turks &amp; Caicos Is</option>
    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States of America</option>
    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="VS">Vatican City State</option>
    <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="VB">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
    <option value="VA">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
    <option value="WK">Wake Island</option>
    <option value="WF">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
    <option value="ZR">Zaire</option>
    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>
    <div class="form-eloqua-separator"></div>
    <span class="form-eloqua-label">Annual Revenue Range</span><select name="C_Annual_Revenue1"> <option value="">Please select ...</option> <option value="0-100,000,000">0-100,000,000</option><option value="100,000,001-300,000,000">100,000,001-300,000,000</option><option value="300,000,001-500,000,000">300,000,001-500,000,000</option><option value="500,000,001-2,000,000,000">500,000,001-2,000,000,000</option><option value="2 Billion +">2 Billion +</option></select>
    <div class="submit-button"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="elqoffer" value="GGB2BContentMktg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="elqchannel" value="TheMarketer" />
    <input type="hidden" name="elqbq" value="14Q2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="elqbc" value="UK" />
    <input type="hidden" name="elqFormName" value="2013-Syndication-1372365875136" />
    <input type="hidden" name="elqSiteId" value="33" />
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

and my PHP code is:

```
    <?php
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT
            echo '<h2>Server Timezone : ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '</h2>';
            $current_date = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s ');
            print "<h2>Server Time : " . $current_date . "</h2>";

            $dataObject = $_POST; //Fetching all posts

            echo "<pre>"; //making the dump look nice in html.
            var_dump($dataObject);
            echo "</pre>";

                //Writes it as json to the file, you can transform it any way you want
            $json = json_encode($dataObject);
            file_put_contents('your_data.txt', $json . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    ?>
```

Comment: That does not make sense, `file_put_contents()` does nothing to scan your file for duplicate lines. What does the function return?

Comment: Did you do any debugging, like checking the return value from f_g_c()? Done an `is_writable('your_data.txt')` test? Plus, you can NOT combine individual json-encoded strings like that, unless you're going to split the file by linebreaks, and hope there's no linebreaks inside the encoded data.

Comment: @MarcB - The file is writable as I can see some data here: http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/your_data.txt Plus, I'd like to have linebreaks after each submission. Any suggestion for code change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood ( after seeing hackingarticles.com/marketer/your_data.txt).Your code look as working. Try change to:

```
$file_content = array();
if ( file_exists('your_data.txt')){
    $file_content = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents('your_data.txt'));
    unlink('your_data.txt');
}

$file_content['users'][] = array('user'=>$_POST);
file_put_contents('your_data.txt',json_encode($file_content));
```

Comment: It doesn't write the data to txt file when the form is submitted after that code executes. Try for yourself here: http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/

Comment: I did. Written `Submission Accepted`

Comment: That message is from an external script. My code is sending data to an external DB as well. Well, I can see your data in txt file now. So if I use FILE_APPEND now, will it append the next submission below your last one?

Comment: Sorry,don`t use FILE_APPEND. Its no sense in this case. Because we get all json data from file. Append new data from $_POST. Then remove old file and puts data to new file. See now.`voodoo416`

Comment: OK. Not using FILE_APPEND but I can't see your voodoo416 submission

Comment: hmmm.. I dont see, too. Show `var_dump($file_content)` before puts.

Comment: It's appending blank entries when the php file is opened. Added var_dump($file_content) before the last line. http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/backend.php

Comment: I update answer . Remove `var_dump($file_content);`. Also you need to 'delete file `your_data.txt`. Try now

Comment: Done. I've posted a form submission. Can you try now and then check http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/your_data.txt

Comment: Still the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: very strange.. some minutes. I am trying

Comment: I updated answer.I am checked - now "appends to end" :). Problem in your json structure. I add entity `users` which contains `user`. You need update new code and remome file `your_data.txt`. Try again

Comment: hmmm.. very strange. I simulate this situation locally. All prorerly works. Try remove these lines ` $dataObject = $_POST;    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($dataObject);echo "</pre>";
        $json = json_encode($dataObject);`. I dont see any mistake in http://jsbin.com/iYESeXe/2/edit.

Comment: Removed those lines but still the same issue. :( Is my HTML/JS code fine?

Comment: http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/your_data.txt Its input two entity `user` but without data. It look as $_POST is empty

Comment: That's because I open backend.php file in browser which sends an empty input. I do that for testing if backend.php is working or not. It's strange that it's passing empty data but not passing form data. That might mean that form fields are not being passed to the PHP correctly?

Comment: I im locally simulate `$_POST['name'] = 'voodoo4';$_POST['email'] = 'email4';`. File look as : `{"users":[{"user":{"name":"voodoo3","email":"email3"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo3","email":"email3"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo3","email":"email3"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo3","email":"email3"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo3","email":"email3"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo3","email":"email3"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo3","email":"email3"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo4","email":"email4"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo4","email":"email4"}},{"user":{"name":"voodoo4","email":"email4"}}]}`

Comment: "`because I open backend.php file in browser which sends an empty input.`" All right. $_POST is empty. Try simulating for testing.

Comment: Hey @voodoo417, I shifted the files to http://redactiveprod.bitnamiapp.com/marketerform/ and now the backend.php isn't even sending blank values to the txt file. the folder/file permissions are 755. Am I missing anything bro?

Comment: sorry, cannot answer on this  question , because i dont know how you sends data: i see only action "http://s33.t.eloqua.com/e/f2" in form there `http://redactiveprod.bitnamiapp.com/marketerform/`

Comment: It's the same form and same code. It's also hosted on the old url which is http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/ It's not working after yesterday

Comment: I cannot check in console ajax-request on `backend.php` due to redirect. try change logic: do form-submit only after getting succes from ajax-response ( from `backend.php`).

Comment: Grab the files from here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mm1tdhr4fe6nstc/S4OT31LAiR and test it out locally if you can :)

Comment: I checked locally. All works properly. File ouptut: `{"users":[{"user":{"C_FirstName":"voodoo416","C_LastName":"voodoo416","C_EmailAddress":"voodoo416@tut.by","C_Title":"","C_Company":"","zipOrPostalCode":"","country":"BY","C_Annual_Revenue1":"","elqoffer":"GGB2BContentMktg","elqchannel":"TheMarketer","elqbq":"14Q2","elqbc":"UK","elqFormName":"2013-Syndication-1372365875136","elqSiteId":"33"}}]}`

Comment: Check your urls and request ($_POST). All json-data is appended normally.

Comment: I see that your output doesn't contain values for all the fields. Can you test it by submitting all the form fields?

Comment: I used code from dropbox and didnt change anything in form html.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. When an email is entered without "@" the text is recorded fine on your_data.txt but when an email is entered with @ like voodoo@test.com then the entry is not submitted to the text file. Can this be an encoding issue @voodoo417?

Comment: hmm... You sure that problem in `@`?

Comment: Yes, test it out and see the results here: http://hackingarticles.com/marketer/your_data.txt

Comment: Fixed it by adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');` as the first line in PHP code. Thanks for all your help mate :D See updated code

Comment: now works:)? But I dont understand how header with content-type affects on work: you only puts to file and doesnt return anything)

Comment: OK. Now it stopped working for some reason. What the hell is this? LOL

Comment: Right. So it's definitely something with the email. Try submitting something and see the text file with and without `@`

Comment: Sorry, I must go. `@` cannot affect on work in this case. For json_encode it is not a problem. Try others options. Hope, I helped you with write full(with new data) json-object, and you could accept my answer.